# React Native Boilerplate failing on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

Why won't this work?? I'd appreciate any help...

I started my React Native project by using the commands

```
npx react-native init ProjectName
npx react-native start
npx react-native run-ios
```

I would think this should work out of the box since I haven't changed anything in the boilerplate but I run into this error (just the tail of the logs since it is very long):

```
CompileC /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.o /Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c++ -target x86_64-apple-ios10.0-simulator -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=c++14 -stdlib\=libc++ -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-overloaded-virtual -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-c++11-extensions -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -Winvalid-offsetof -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wmove -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wrange-loop-analysis -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -index-store-path /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/ReactCommon-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/include -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Private -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/ReactCommon -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/DoubleConversion -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/RCT-Folly -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-callinvoker -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-cxxreact -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsi -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsiexecutor -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-jsinspector -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-perflogger -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-runtimeexecutor -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/ReactCommon -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/glog -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/boost-for-react-native -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/DoubleConversion -I/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Private/React-Core -I/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64 -I/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FlipperKit/FlipperKit.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React/React-Core.modulemap -fmodule-map-file\=/Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/yoga/Yoga.modulemap -DFOLLY_NO_CONFIG -DFOLLY_MOBILE\=1 -DFOLLY_USE_LIBCPP\=1 -Wno-comma -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wno-documentation -include /Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/ReactCommon/ReactCommon-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.dia -c /Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/TurboModuleBinding.cpp -o /Users/kenjohnson/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/musu-dxuzhjabsbtpkngvripniybslkco/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TurboModuleBinding.o

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-DoubleConversion' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 5.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'CocoaAsyncSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'YogaKit' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
        CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/kenjohnson/Documents/Projects/Personal/musu/ios/Pods/YogaKit/YogaKit/Source/YGLayoutExtensions.swift
(2 failures)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I have googled this error and I have found some fixes/workarounds but I'm wondering: **how can I fix this for good so I don't run into this issue every time I start a new project (eg is there something I need to update)?**

Comment: Does this also happen when you run the project from Xcode?

Comment: yes unfortunately it does

Comment: Just a guess, but are you missing step `pod install`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try clear Xcode cache and remove `derivedData`. That's located in this directory : `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Do not forget to clean your build also, can be done through Xcode -> Product -> clean build Folder.

If you want to, you can also check this very simple react native boilerplate by handi.dev, which is contain minimum third party library, have a try: **https://github.com/handi-dev/react-native-boilerplate**

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the terminal and run the commands again and if that doesn't work try restarting your mac.

There is an open issue about this on react native GitHub issues and still didn't resolved. You can check here about the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28777

Answer (score 0):

If you are on M1 Mac, try to delete Flipper lines in your pod file and then "pod install" and build again.